# Pandas values substituted by numpy matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, addition, subtraction

My question is very simple. I have a dataFrame and I want to add or substract my DataFrame by a numpy matrix.
The size of the two matrix are identical.
I would like this kind of things : `my_matrix.values = my_matrix.values + numpy_matrix`, or `my_matrix.values = my_matrix.values - numpy_matrix`, very efficiently.

Is not possible? Because the size of ma matrix is quite huge and the "update", subtract or the "add" command is quite long. Is it better to recreate a DataFrame each time?

Comment: edited. Sorry, it was unclear.

Comment: An example data would be better to understand

Comment: To be very simple : if `A = (1)ij`, and `B = (2) ij`,  `C = A + B = (3)ij`.
I just want to sum two matrix with numpy and put the values into the dataframe. The calcul is very simple but the matrix are large >20 000. Is it possible to do this without "update"? or "add"? Or recreate a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]],columns=['A','B'])
my_arr = np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])

df += my_arr

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  3  4
1  5  6
```

Comment: So simple!!! I tried several SOOOO complicated things. Thanks a lot. You saved me 4 hours of calculus.

Comment: Simple and fair enough.

Comment: Maybe one more thing. To use your method, I need my first df is plenty without NaN, otherwise some of sum don't happen. In the case I have a NaN, I should use fillna(0) and a loss a lot of time. It exists a solution to sum `NaN + num = num` efficiently?
In this worse case, I need to `df = df.fillna(0) + df_arr.`

Comment: @Cyril `df = df.add(my_arr, fill_value=0)`  That this instead of previous statement, however your statement should work too.

Comment: %timeit prefere my approach than yours. Thank you for your solution. Sometimes, the optimization is very simple.